# Recursive type conversion between two Go structs with parallel structure

Tags: go, type-conversion

**Short Question:**

Is it possible to do type conversion in Go between two different structs, if both of those structs contain fields that are also struct (different types, but compatible)? See Example 2 below for what I'd like to achieve.

I suspect this is not possible since the types of A and B are not identical any more, but am wondering if this could somehow be achieved with type conversion?

**Background:**

I'm working on a REST API (let's call it X) that is mostly a tiny wrapper around another REST API (Y). One of the endpoints I'm building in X, I'm mostly just exposing the response from Y, but I do need to rename the JSON field names. If the response from Y is one-level (i.e. without nested structs) I can do the renaming by type conversion as shown in Example 1. However, if the response from Y contains nested structs, the type conversion does not seem to work any more, assuming we want to rename fields on both levels (i.e. on the parent and the child). See Example 2.

For example, I'd like to map the JSON from Y:

```json
{
    "Num": 1,
    "Child": {
        "Num": 2
    }

}
```

to a response in X:

```json
{
    "NumB": 1,
    "Child": {
        "NumB": 2
    }

}
```

I know there are also other ways on how the JSON field names could be renamed, but I'm just wondering it something like this could be achieved with type conversion.

**Example 1 (conversion passes without issues):**

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    type A struct {
        Num int
    }

    type B struct {
        Num int `json:"NumB"`
    }

    a := A{1}
    b := B(a) // works

    fmt.Println(b)
}
```

**Example 2 (does not compile):**

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    type AC struct {
        Num int
    }

    type A struct {
        Num   int
        Child AC
    }

    type BC struct {
        Num int `json:"NumB"`
    }

    type B struct {
        Num   int `json:"NumB"`
        Child BC  `json:"Child"`
    }

    a := A{1, AC{2}}
    b := B(a) // does not work

    fmt.Println(b)
}
```

I get the following error:

```sh
./main.go:25:8: cannot convert a (type A) to type B
```

Comment: That is correct, you will need to convert this recursively yourself, the language does not support this automatically.

Comment: What happens when you try? I imagine you can test this faster than you can ask the question. (And indeed, it seems you have)

Comment: @Flimzy I've tested and it fails. I was just wondering if this is something that is not supported by the language, or if I'm doing something wrong. And according to JimB, this is not supported by the language.

Comment: https://github.com/jinzhu/copier ?

Comment: @mh-cbon thanks! That looks promising :)

Comment: @nikicc make it an answer if that works

Comment: @mh-cbon that's another solution to the problem. There are plenty more. I was trying to do this with built-in conversion, if possible, which seem to not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

According to [@JimB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/32880/jimb) comment: such conversions are not supported by the language (as least not in Go 1.15).

Some of the alternatives for mapping such structs:

- manually copying fields from one struct to the other
- https://github.com/jinzhu/copier (as [@mh-cbon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4466350/mh-cbon) suggested)
- https://github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure

Comment: this lacks some code example to demonstrate pros and cons of each solution.

Comment: @mh-cbon I don't agree completely. The question was about recursive type conversion between Go structs, and the answer to that question is that it is not possible. It's true that I used the JSON field renaming as an example, hence I've put the possible solutions for that in the answer as well. But comparing them feels out of scope. If you want to elaborate more, feel free to do so :)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/347939/4466350  `3. Don't post just a link to answer a question.`

Comment: `But comparing them feels out of scope.` agreed, this is up to you.

Comment: @mh-cbon I agree just pasting links is bad. However, the pasted links are not directly relevant to the question. The questions is "Is it possible to do type conversion in Go between two different structs that contain fields that are also structs?". And the answer is given straight: with type conversion this is not possible.

IMHO we shouldn't even put the links in, as they are not directly relevant to the type conversion question, but I've put them in on your request. I totally understand if we disagree about this, and encourage you to post another answer with more details.

Comment: I suppose it would have been less efforts ^ ^

Comment: though, i am unsure, did it solve your issue ?

Comment: @mh-cbon I probably would have, but we are leaning towards manually copying the fields. E.g. something like `b := B{a.Num, BC{a.Child.Num}}`.

Comment: that s bad. Can you elaborate about the reasoning ? the examples you have provided appeared to be a perfect fit when i checked for copier.

Comment: @mh-cbon cuz it is build-in and explicit. I'm not saying everyone should do it that way. I'm just saying that's what we've decided (and it might turn out to be a wrong decision, we'll see).